# check if user ID is reserved or not

Tags: linux, debian, users

I have Linux server (Debian 8.6) that has both local users and LDAP users, I want to create users with specific ID (via script), but I want to make sure it (ID) isn't reserved by local or LDAP user, our LDAP user has hundreds of users and manual search will take forever.

Comment: `getent passwd <id>`?

Comment: @muru Thanks, did not though of this option, this will work.